# how to compile spring-boot-maven-plugin without dependencies?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am trying to do an excercise with micro-services in Java with Spring boot, for this I am developing two web services in different projects with the intention of deploying them in tomcat like two independent files (.war).

I have read about set up tomcat to have the dependencies in an specified folder to share it with other services and this way not to increase the same libraries in all services.

The ploblem is that when I compiled the service with maven through the artifact spring-boot-maven-plugin the .war files always has the dependencies inside. Because of I want to know if someone know how to configure maven to 
remove dependencies from .war file..... in Spring Boot.

The .war follows with the dependencies inside, Edited:
I have added the provided like said Michael Potter and the execution. it works fine.  My pom.xml is the follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>demo1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
              <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
              <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Maven not to include dependency in your WAR file you need to specify its **scope** to **provided**. The description of the scope from official Maven documentation:

> This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a
>   container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when
>   building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would
>   set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to
>   scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This
>   scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is
>   not transitive.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.192</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The dependency will be downloaded to compile the sources, but not packed in the WAR.

Concerning *spring-boot-maven-plugin*. By default it makes repackaging of a WAR that allows you to launch it from console. Thus, it packages all required dependencies to the archive - even with the **provided** scope. You can see in your target directory two files: *{project-name}.war* which is repackaged and *{project-name}.war.original* - the one that should not contain provided dependencies. To disable repackaging you should change *spring-boot-maven-plugin* configuration to the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then you need to place the required dependency to *tomcat/lib* folder and restart the Tomcat.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for you help, however It does not work in spring boot. I do not know the cause.

Comment: I have edited the question and I have added the pom.xml, however it is not the solution for me.

Comment: You should leave test scope for test dependencies like spring-boot-starter-test as dependencies with that scope either do not packed to WAR.

Comment: @J.Abel, I extended response with information about spring-boot-maven-plugin. It should help to get rid of dependencies in your WAR

Comment: Hi. ¡It works!, Thanks @Michael Potter, with the scope and the executions in the plugin it works fine.