# Is it possible to create a spring-boot custom parent pom this is also a multi module project?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, multi-module

I would like to know how to set up a parent pom that handles my spring-boot dependencies as well as builds a few client jars.

```
Parent Project
|- client-jar-1
|  |- src/main/java/MyPojo.java
|  |- pom.xml (parent super pom? <package> type is jar) 
|- pom.xml (parent is spring-boot-starter-parent <package> type is pom)

Child Project
|- pom.xml (parent pom is custom parent-project, includes client-jar-1 as a dependency)
```

My thought process is the the parent project can handle common dependencies across multiple independent spring applications and also build a few custom client jars or utility jars, that the child project could include at their own discretion.

Here is my first attempt at my pom files:

**Parent Project POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.me.spring.boot.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>me-spring-boot-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>directory_client</module>
    </modules>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>9</source>
                        <target>9</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**client-jar-1 POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>me-spring-boot-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.me.spring.boot.parent</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.me.directory.cleint</groupId>
    <artifactId>directory-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
</project>
```

**Child Project POM**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.me</groupId>
    <artifactId>child-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.me.spring.boot.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>me-spring-boot-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <flyway.url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db</flyway.url>
        <flyway.driver>org.postgresql.Driver</flyway.driver>
        <flyway.sqlMigrationSeparator>.sql</flyway.sqlMigrationSeparator>
        <flyway.sqlMigrationSuffixes></flyway.sqlMigrationSuffixes>
    </properties>
</project>
```

In my Child project when I try and access the client-jar-1 `MyPojo` I get a compilation error. Here is the expanded dependency from the child project

[image]

I can even get my IDE to import the MyPojo class, but there is a problem with the packages and it can't truly resolve the class.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, in your parent pom add :

```
<modules>
    <module>child1</module>
    <module>child2</module>
</modules>
```

And in your child1 and child2 pom add :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>yourorganization</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
</parent>
```

The parent pom will contain the `spring-boot-starter-parent`

Comment: I have this setup. Sorry I’ll post my full POMs soon. When I run `mvn clean instal`l on the parent project it builds and installs to my **.m2** but then when I try and access MyPojo from the child project my I can’t compile my child

Comment: If Child Project depends on client-jar you should add it in its pom. So add client-jar in Child Project pom

Comment: Sorry, it’s actually added as a dependency in the child project. I think the problem is with how the parent is packaging the client-jar. Notice that MyPojo is under the BOOT-INF directory when I think com should be at the root

Comment: You have defined only one module in your parent pom. I hope you solved your problem

Comment: The issue was actually related to the fact that my custom parent pom was inheriting from the `spring-boot-starter-parent` which attempts to package the the parent as a deployable JAR, when I need it to be packed as a plain old JAR. The solution was to add a `<skip>true</skip>` to the build pluginManagemnt in my client-jar-1 POM  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448183/how-to-compile-spring-boot-maven-plugin-without-dependencies